# Where "do" substitutes for other verbs, when can we omit it?

Tags: modal-verbs

> I haven't seen her yet, but maybe I will [**do**] tomorrow.
>
> I didn't hit the ball as well as I wanted to, but maybe I will [**do**] tomorrow.
>
> I can't believe it now, but maybe I will [**do**] tomorrow when I go to Korea.

Searching on Internet for a preliminary comprehension about this matter, I found nothing that could precisely indicate what the valid form is. "I will tomorrow" and "I will **do** tomorrow" are used apparently as if they were completely interchangeable.

Please, explain when we can drop the **do** in these kind of constructions.

Comment: Easy one: always. In fact, the *do* is rare in US usage.

Comment: Perhaps it's just my habit that comes into play here, but I'd use "do" in your sentences if there were an object and I'd drop it otherwise. So "... I will do **it** / **so** tomorrow" but not "... maybe I will tomorrow".

Answer (score 1):

In all of your examples, I'd omit the *do* (in GB usage).

I agree with Paola that I'd probably only include *do* when I need *do it*.
e.g. person A: *Did you telephone Fred today?* person B: *No. I'll do it tomorrow.*

Comment: I have an American friend who would say: "No, but I will do tomorrow". As StoneyB says, though, it's rare in American English.